# How can I use a variable inside a RegEx (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I already looked at the Mozzila website and W3schools but couldn't find the answer

```
var someFunction = function (someString, someOtherString)
{
   if (someOtherString.match(someString))
   {
     someString = new RegExp(someString);
     someOtherString = someOtherString.replace(someString, "XXX");
     return someOtherString;
   }

   return null;
};

someFunction("dog", "dogeatdog");
```

Now I want the above RegExp to be applied **globally** but I don't know where/how to add the `g` character so that the above function call returns `XXXeatXXX`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

*Flags* go in the second argument of the [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Constructor), eg

```
new RegExp(someString, 'g')
```